# How can I remotely control electrical devices?

Tags: lighting, home-automation

how can i turn on remotely or turn off the lights or TV with remote controller or via internet

which tools i need to prepare or buy to make the circuit or device that do this work?

is there any way to turn off all forget lights in 1 am.?

Comment: This question is way to broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends in which country you are living in.

In the UK, Russia and Australia - C-Bus
In America - Lutron

Worldwide - Crestron (Expensive)

Answer (score 2):

There are a large number of ways to do this - lots of people DIY it, but there are very simple commercial solutions out there too.

[X10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29) is probably the best known standard.

Have a look at the [UK home automation site](http://www.uk-automation.co.uk/) for lots of info.

A bit more fun if you are a gadget freak or a tinkerer is [Electric Imp](http://electricimp.com/) - started by a guy from google and the guy who designed most of the iPhone hardware (as well as designing the [best car stereo ever](http://empegbbs.com/) - even now 15 years later) - this device lets you make **any** device in your house Internet controllable :-)